# Install Ansible Tower in specific directory

Tags: redhat, storage, ansible, ansible-tower, rhel8

Can you mount a second drive at /opt/ansible and tell Tower to install there instead so it won't affect a boot partition? What are some considerations if you can?

Comment: I was  under the impression the prefered method was to install via docker.  If you use docker, bind mount the volumes to wherever you want them to be.

Answer (score 0):

According Ansible Tower [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/administration/tipsandtricks.html), it uses Python `virtualenv`, so you could make own `virtualenv` for own proposes as it's described in mentioned documentation.